# typescript destructuring assignment with interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I tried to destructuring  assignment with interface, but cannot write like this.

```
interface TYPE {
  id?: number;
  type?: string;
}

const e =  {
  'id': 123,
  'type': 'type_x',
  'other': 'other_x'
}
const {...foo}: {foo: TYPE} = e;
console.log(foo.id, foo.type) // expected: 123, 'type_x'
```

Comment: What do you expect `const {...foo}: {foo: TYPE} = e;` to do exactly?

Comment: const {...foo, ...rest}: {foo: TYPE, rest: any} = e,; to desctruct assign TYPE, and rest propterties, but not write like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare the type on the variable, without that weird object notation:

```
const { ...foo }: TYPE = e;
```

That is a weird way to make a copy of an object however - it's usually done like so:

```
const foo: TYPE = { ...e };
```

Comment: What does `const { ...foo }: TYPE = e;` even mean? Why not `const foo = e;`?

Comment: Because without the spreading, it would create a reference rather than a shallow copy.

Comment: Then that's a weird way to do that: `const foo = { ...e };` is how it's usually done.

Comment: Yeah, but that's how the OP did it.

Comment: Just to clarify, I just +1'd your answer, and I don't think it's anything wrong with it. What they do is weird though, so for clarity would you please add the other option as well? :-)

Comment: I want to  destruct with interface and rest properties, I post another [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346829/typescript-destructuring-assignment-with-interface-and-rest-properties) to ask this.